# Count the number of times an element occurs in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

I have an Array which has the elements `[50, 20, 20, 5, 2]`, called `coins_used`.

I need to count and then output the number of times a coin occurs in the Array. using the output of `coin_used x frequency`.

Is there anyway that I can count the number of times an element occurs in the array, the output needs to be exactly like this:

`50x1,20x2,5x1,2x1`

How would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at various methods available in Array class - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html ?  What have you tried before posting your question?

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq), you can get unique elements of the array. And [`Array#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-count) will return the number of items found in the array.

By [joining](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) the mapped array with `,`, you can get what you want:

```
a = [50,20,20,5,2]
a.uniq.map { |x| "#{x}x#{a.count(x)}" }.join(',')
# => "50x1,20x2,5x1,2x1"
```

**UPDATE** More efficient version that use [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) to count.

```
a = [50,20,20,5,2]
freq = Hash.new(0)
a.each { |x| freq[x] += 1 }
freq.map{ |key, value| "#{key}x#{value}" }.join(',')
# => "50x1,20x2,5x1,2x1"
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Ah.. I updated the answer. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 3):

With `Ruby >= 2.7` you can do:

```
coins_used = [50, 20, 20, 5, 2]
tally = coins_used.tally
tally.map { |k,v| "#{k}x#{v}" }.join(',')
=> "50x1,20x2,5x1,2x1"
```

Answer (score 1):

ruby stdlib really should include a method like this (it's in my `.pryrc`, I use it daily)

```
module Enumerable
  def count_by(&block)
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |elem, memo|
      value = block.call(elem)
      memo[value] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

You use it like this:

```
[50, 20, 20, 5, 2].count_by{|e| e} # => {50=>1, 20=>2, 5=>1, 2=>1}
# ruby 2.2
[50, 20, 20, 5, 2].count_by(&:itself) # => {50=>1, 20=>2, 5=>1, 2=>1}
```

Transforming this hash to string of desired format is on you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) with [`itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-itself):

```
a = [50,20,20,5,2]
a.group_by(&:itself).map { |k, v| "#{k}x#{v.size}" }.join(',')
# => "50x1,20x2,5x1,2x1"
```